# Вирус?Wordpress. Непонятный PHP код

Tags: php, html, wordpress, вирусы

В папке контент появился файл WFCE и дальше много цифер и букв разных. Помогите. Что делать?

**backup-data.php**

```
# No direct access
$secureSrcClassName  = 'WCFE\Modules\Editor\Model\EmergencyRestore';
( class_exists( $secureSrcClassName ) && ( get_class( $this ) == $secureSrcClassName ) ) or die( 'Access Denied' );

$data = array();

$data[ 'secureKey' ]    = 'bd8c7c7d3d22910492ef8b27788440f0';
$data[ 'backupFileHash' ]   = '4d169695428e796bd128e3ae92c0dcf5';

$data[ 'absPath' ]  = '/home/c/cc27828/thealltopg/public_html';
$data[ 'contentDir' ]   = '/home/c/cc27828/thealltopg/public_html/wp-content/wcfe-c8113601f2e0cea774aa19827b7c3e9e';

$data[ 'timeCreated' ]  = 1614433954;

$data[ 'privateKey' ] = 'IKQHHUZ,&s1GOs3*<d!%N<-F<st-&k. dvlBwV77Zp>yheyu8JBJz:?{|_{[ h</%`EGcO*]P/Xp/$>uy+T%X1sn&Fh(xhG-6;a t|3Sz:uQBH0cb~oZXsHH}7w(TG4K]e@(h3ltv>oJ*)!`h#qwR(9L#s+qa(cyFEABN?k`|Tl~# _,^Xa)Ifjkj2F8LjKPa1<F`L4 tluhp[GV^K03$q]O]M3h-}J]jGGth7$*Iij+K;6VryY:N)ZRwsYPxZ_KOabc[a8g#e)#F{zw35{?${Kmy01!EH@-R>U,{3FVr(p:T1(K8*aDbN)jQ;.6!`PL2Lx+}X:EkYYMkvL71@QrZQ090vX>%&5}JXk~AXcKsmi_iHeC#LICH @?fiHpPL2!PeoQQ!re-(Y[Vt~2{4)L?Zuz`;^tkctyC%#Ppp)Bb}(tS+&-z2Cx4fOQ@]MB3f`u 5Le/Na>AR<PIyM5*sH8R4K_ufK4MsInrLqyFeLL7->l&r{!g(F$5Q${ff1Uk)a+'; 

return $data;
?>
```

**.htaccess**

```
<Files *>
    Order Allow,Deny
    Deny from all
</Files>
```

**wp-config-backup.php**

`````
<?php


# No direct access
$secureSrcClassName  = 'WCFE\Modules\Editor\Model\EmergencyRestore';
( class_exists( $secureSrcClassName ) && ( get_class( $this ) == $secureSrcClassName ) && $this->isConfirmed() ) or die( 'Access Denied' );


return array( 'content' => '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 

```` и дальше тоже много букав
`````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это не вирус. Это файлы от плагина [WP Config File Editor](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-config-file-editor/). Он в таком виде сохраняет резервные копии при изменение конфиг файлов

Comment: Серьезно?А, блин, можно сделать еще подозрительней? Спасибо

Comment: @Новичок можете написать разработчикам на страницу плагина https://wordpress.org/support/plugin/wp-config-file-editor/ по поводу подозрительности